# Can't install vuejs in laravel project on fedora28

Tags: npm-install

When running:

```
$sudo npm install
```

these three warnings appear:

> npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
>
> npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
>
> npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? In any case, all this is telling you that something in your project is depending on deprecated versions of libraries

Comment: i saw it in a tutorial

Comment: i tried sudo npm prune  and now the all packages are removed  put still getting :

Comment: ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/home/ahmed/Ahmed/projects30.8/larticles_api/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11)

Comment: so how to check the  (libpng-dev) or what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the os and just inserting  $ sudo dnf install nodejs
now it works
The problem was that i installed npm twice:
in fedora 28 when inserting  $ sudo dnf install nodejs
it install both npm and nodejs 
so  i don't have to insert  $ sudo dnf install npm